# Recorrer árbol n-ario en PROLOG

Tags: prolog, árboles

El predicado que quiero hacer en prolog debe recorrer un árbol n-ario y guardar los valores de cada nodo en una lista. Para representar un árbol uso dos estructuras: `hoja/1` y `nodo/2`.

- `hoja(N)` representa una hoja con un valor `N` (en notación de Peano).
- `nodo(N,Hijos)` representa un nodo con un valor `N` y una lista que contiene hijos.

Por ejemplo:

- Un árbol con un único nodo que vale `2` se representaría como `hoja(s(s(0)))`.
- Un árbol con una raíz que vale `1`, y dos hijos que valen `2` y `3`, se representaría como `nodo(s(0),[hoja(s(s(0))),hoja(s(s(s(0))))]`

Además, como es normal, un nodo puede contener mas nodos en su lista de hijos.

Este es mi programa:

```
recorrer(nodo(A,L),Res):-
    miAppend(A,Res,Res2),
    recorrer(L,Res2).

recorrer(hoja(N),N).

%Cuando le paso a recorrer una hoja, funciona

%El problema es que cuando recibe un nodo, a la siguiente iteración de recorrer se le pasa una %lista de Hijos, y no tengo ningún predicado que plantee esa situación. Pero es que no se como %hacerlo. 
He probado con un predicado que recibe una lista, borra la cabeza y vuelve a%recorrer, %pero me sigue sin funcionar:    

%recorrer([Cabeza|Lista],Res):-
%       borrar([Cabeza|Lista],Lista2),
%       recorrer(Lista2,Res).           %Sigue sin funcionar


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

miAppend([], Cs, Cs). 
miAppend([A|As],Bs,[A|Cs]):-
    miAppend(As, Bs, Cs).
```

Ya no se como hacerlo.
Gracias a quien pueda ayudar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El caso base es llegar a una hoja, donde se devuelve una lista con ese único elemento:

```
elementos(hoja(X), [X]).
```

En los nodos, se devuelve una lista con el valor del nodo como cabeza, y los elementos de sus hijos como cola, que serán la concatenación de los elementos de todos sus hijos:

```
elementos(nodo(X,Xs), [X|Ys]) :- elementos(Xs, Ys).
```

Ahora hay que tratar la lista de árboles, para ir concatenando sus elementos:

```
elementos([],[]).
elementos([X|Xs],Zs) :- elementos(X,Y), elementos(Xs,Ys), append(Y,Ys,Zs).
```

Por ejemplo:

```
?- elementos(nodo(1, [nodo(2, [hoja(5)]), nodo(3, [hoja(6), nodo(7, [hoja(8)])])]), X).
X = [1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 8]
```

## Peano

Nótese que con el predicado anterior, da igual lo que contengan los nodos. Si quieres que sólo recoja como elementos números de Peano, habría que añadir una comprobación:

```
peano(0).
peano(s(X)) :- peano(X).

elementos(hoja(X),[X]) :- peano(X), !.
elementos(hoja(_),[]).
elementos(nodo(X,Xs),[X|Ys]) :- peano(X), !, elementos(Xs,Ys).
elementos(nodo(_,Xs),Ys) :- elementos(Xs,Ys).
elementos([],[]).
elementos([X|Xs],Zs) :- elementos(X,Y), elementos(Xs,Ys), append(Y,Ys,Zs).
```

Ahora únicamente añadiría a la lista números de Peano, ignorando el resto:

```
?- elementos(nodo(s(0), [nodo(s(s(0)), [hoja(5)]), nodo(3, [hoja(6), nodo(7, [hoja(s(s(s(s(0)))))])])]), X).
X = [s(0), s(s(0)), s(s(s(s(0))))].
```

## Estructura de datos

Una consideración respecto a las estructuras que estás utilizando para representar el árbol. No es necesario que distingas explícitamente un nodo y una hoja con dos términos diferentes, ya que una hoja se puede representar como un nodo sin hijos (una lista vacía): `hoja(X) :- nodo(X,[]).`.

```
elementos(nodo(X,Xs),[X|Ys]) :- elementos(Xs,Ys).
elementos([],[]).
elementos([X|Xs],Zs) :- elementos(X,Y), elementos(Xs,Ys), append(Y,Ys,Zs).
```

Con esta nueva representación, reducimos el predicado anterior y seguirá funcionando:

```
?- elementos(nodo(1,[nodo(2,[]),nodo(3,[nodo(4,[]),nodo(5,[])])]),X).
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

## Recorridos

Hay varias formas de recorrer el árbol, según el orden en el que se visitan los nodos:

- **Preorden**: Visitar primero la raíz, y luego los hijos.
- **Inorden**: Visitar primero el primer hijo, luego la raíz, y después el resto.
- **Postorden**: Visitar primero los hijos, y después la raíz.

Puedes tratar de implementar los otros dos recorridos a partir del preorden.